# Can we validate .0 using regex

Tags: html, angularjs, regex, typescript

I'm doing a field that will only accept whole numbers.  So I did a regex validation like this /^\d{1,3}$/ this is validating whole number entry and does not allow decimal from .1 e.g it will make 1.1 invalid but when I tried to input 1.0 it accepted it.  Is there a regex that will also check .0?

Comment: This regex should not accept anything other than one, two or three digit numbers. Try it on https://regexr.com/. It doesn't accept 1.0

Comment: Thanks man, yeah seems to work in the regex checker.  But when I'm using it in typescript it's not.

Comment: I tried `var regexp = /^\d{1,3}$/g; alert(regexp.test('1.0'));` on https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/. It displays false. Can you share the code that you're using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^\d{1,3}(\.0)?$` accepts one, two or three digit whole numbers as well as if they end with `.0`.